# How do I stack multiple conditions in a column in math mode?

Tags: stacking-symbols

I am experimenting with multiple integrals and volume (and area) elements.

I can write the integral,

```
$A = \int_a^t{\left|f\left(x\right)\right|dx} $,
```

as

```
$A = \int_a^t{\int_0^{\left|f\left(x\right)\right|} dy \, dx} $
```

but writing it as

```
$A = \int_{ {a \le s_x \le t} \; \wedge \; {0 \le s_y \le \left|f\left(s_x\right)\right|}} ds$
```

gets ugly and long and I would like to collapse the conditions into a column sort of like with

```
$A = \int_{ \overset{a \le s_x \le t}{0 \le s_y \le \left|f\left(s_x\right)\right|}} ds$
```

but with both conditions being the same size.

How do I stack multiple conditions in a column in math mode?

Comment: You seem to believe that `\left` and `\right` are mandatory: they aren't. Also `\int` doesn't take an argument: it's not `\int{f(x)dx}`, but more simply `\int f(x)dx` Better yet, `\int f(x)\,dx`.

Answer (score 2):

The `stackengine` and `mathtools` packages might give you more control an the vertical and horizontal spacing. Also, I remove some sputious `\left … \right` pairs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\setstackgap{L}{1.8ex}

\begin{document}

\[ A = \int_{\mspace{1mu}\everymath{\scriptstyle }\Vectorstack[l]{a \le s_x \le t\\\mathrlap{0 \le s_y \le |f(s_x)|} }}\, f(s)\,ds \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\substack` command to stack multiple conditions; it was originally designed for limits of operators, e.g. `\sum_{\substack{j=1 \\ j\ne i}}`, but works well for integrals too:

```
\int\limits_{\substack{a\le s\le t\\ 0 \le s_y \le |f(s_x)|}
  f(s)\, ds
```

[image]

Comment: The `\left` and `\right` in that formula can and should be omitted.

Comment: @egreg: done. I just used OP's code, but thanks for the tip! I've edited my answer.